# Problems with my tooltip on a custom control (xaml wpf)

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my first post on stackoverflow and i'm new to xaml and wpf.

I have a custom control that I'm working on and I want to add a tooltip to that can be setup when the control is declared. I have managed to get the get the tooltip working the way I want it to using the style template as shown below, however I'm having problems with the tooltip appearing even when I have no text setup for it.

I have tried to cut out any of the code in the snippet below to leave only the code concerned with the tooltip.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0" Width="{TemplateBinding BtnWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding BtnHeight}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                   <Grid.ToolTip>
                        <Border 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding TooltipBorderColour}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding TooltipBackground}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding TooltipBorderThickness}" 
                                CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding TooltipCornerRadius}" 
                                >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock 
                                            Text="{TemplateBinding TooltipText}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding TooltipFontColour}" 
                                            FontStyle="{TemplateBinding TooltipFontStyle}" 
                                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding TooltipFontFamily}" 
                                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding TooltipFontSize}" 
                                            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding TooltipFontWeight}"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding TooltipTextMargin}"
                                            >
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid.ToolTip>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="TooltipText" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define the `ToolTip` as: `ToolTipService.ToolTip` and then add a trigger to disable it, the `ToolTip` already does all the logic in the background.

Declare your `ToolTip` directly on the Grid like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ToolTip>
    Add your tool tip stuff here...
  </Grid.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```

**Edit**
Change your trigger to this:

```
<Trigger Property="TooltipText" Value="">
  <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Trigger>
```

This will force the grid to remove the `ToolTip` when the text is "".

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have modified me xaml as you suggested. My tooltip still shows even when I have not set any text to it. I have changed my code snippet to reflex the changes that I have made.

Comment: Any ideas how I can now edit tooltip properties such as the ShowDurationProperty within my style template?